# How can I set an output directory for rdmd (Windows)?

Tags: d, dmd

I know, that in **dmd** it can be done like this:

```
> cd ..\bin
> dmd ..\src\example.d
```

or like this:

```
> dmd example.d -offilename ..\bin\example.exe
```

But in **rdmd** this methods doesn't work. File "example.exe" always appears in the same folder with "example.d".

I tried to do this

```
> rdmd --build-only example.d ..\bin\example.exe
```

, this

```
> rdmd --build-only example.d -offilename ..\bin\example.exe
```

and this

```
> cd ..\bin && rdmd --build-only ..\src\example.d
```

with the same negative result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You got the syntax of `-offilename` wrong. `filename` is a sample value. You need to replace it: `-of..\bin\example.exe`. Many other dmd options work in the same way.

Also, rdmd doesn't pass arguments that come after the source file to dmd. They are interpreted as arguments to the program that's built and run (regardless of `--build-only`). That means, you need to put `-of..\bin\example.exe` before `example.d`:

`rdmd --build-only -of..\bin\example.exe example.d`

Comment: yes, it was because of the wrong order of arguments

Answer (score 3):

With 'of' option, it is meant that you replace the 'filename' with the name of your output file, like this:

```
rdmd --build-only -of../bin/example.exe example.d
```

This works for me in my projects' [makefile](https://github.com/mkoskim/games/blob/master/engine/build/Makegame.mak). EDIT: I forgot that the order of arguments also matters with DMD.

Comment: Note: Only rdmd cares about the order of arguments, dmd accepts them in any order.